# InvalidParameterException: instanceId longer than 36

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-ecs

I am running:

```
aws ecs start-task --cluster default --task-definition tobi-test-task:4 --container-instance arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:container-instance/i-083adb2301e80f09c
```

but getting:

```
A client error (InvalidParameterException) occurred when calling the StartTask operation: instanceId longer than 36.
```

The instanceId is 19 characters (which is less than 36).

[Official ARN namespaces](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html)

Comment: Can you try: `--container-instance i-083adb2301e80f09c`

Comment: InvalidParameterException: instanceId shorter than 36 :-)

Answer (score 7):

The container instance is a GUID of 32 characters that looks like
67fbef1c-474f-46cb-a8bb-b2f923e21234

You can get this list via the command (note that, I've had to explicitly say --cluster, or else you'll get back an empty list):

`$ aws ecs list-clusters
   ... you'll see your clusters here ...
$ aws ecs list-container-instances --cluster arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:181312345678:cluster/myown-ServiceECSCluster-13XI13N9EQCXZ
   ... grab your GUIDs here ...`

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't look like a valid container instance ARN, but rather the ARN prefix for a container instance followed by an EC2 instance ID.  A valid container instance ARN will have that prefix followed by a GUID.  You can see the container instance IDs in your cluster by calling `ListContainerInstances` for your cluster.

Comment: `aws ecs list-container-instances` `{
    "containerInstanceArns": []
}`
you've seen the actual issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42587923/aws-ecs-firstrun-not-showing-ec2-instance ;-)