# AWS ECS firstRun not showing EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

I went through the *firstRun* steps [here](https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/ecs/home?region=us-west-2#/firstRun) (AWS login required).

I have uploaded a docker image to the ECR and the cluster launches successfully, all steps succeed (*ECS status - 4 of 4 complete* and *EC2 instance status - 14 of 14 complete*).

There is no instance attached to the cluster although it is running (see screenshots). What am I doing wrong?

[image: ECR cluster instances]
[image: EC2 cluster instance]

Comment: What is the IAM policy for `EMR_EC2_DefaultRule`?  Have you followed the troubleshooting guide? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/troubleshooting.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The permissions were missing, or in other words, *EMR_EC2_DefaultRule* wasn't a *AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role*.

It's explained [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/instance_IAM_role.html?shortFooter=true).

Would've expected the setup to fail if the role does not grant enough permissions for the EC2 instance to actually connect to the cluster.

Comment: I had the same problem, and found that my instance was also missing the appropriate IAM role. Another symptom I noticed was the `ecs-agent` docker container was constantly restarting. `/var/log/ecs/ecs-init.log` contains repeated `Starting Amazon EC2 Container Service Agent` and related entries.